# Cross compile perl for QNX 6.6.0 armle v7

Tags: linux, perl, compilation, cross-compiling, qnx

I'm trying to cross compile perl 5.24  using following method since the target machine does not have ssh installed.
https://github.com/arsv/perl-cross

Just for Fyi, my local machine is ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux.

I configure the toolchain with the following option:

./configure -Dsysroot=$QNX_TARGET -Dcc=ntoarmv7-gcc -Dtargetarch=armle -Dprefix=$HOME/localperl -Duseshrplib

The reason I think the above scripts worked just fine because it generates the makefile with the following message:

```
Generating config.h
Extracting config.h (with variable substitutions)
Generating Makefile.config
Configuration completed for native build

        platform:  x86_64-
      c compiler:  ntoarmv7-gcc
              ld:  ntoarmv7-gcc
              ar:  ar
          ranlib:  ranlib
```

when i run the make -j4 option i end up getting either of the following 2 results:

```
./generate_uudmap uudmap.h bitcount.h mg_data.h
./generate_uudmap: 1: ./generate_uudmap: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
make: *** [uudmap.h] Error 2
```

OR

```
cp -f op.c opmini.c
cp -f perl.c perlmini.c
cp -f ext/re/re.pm lib/re.pm
sh cflags.SH
cp -f dist/ExtUtils-ParseXS/lib/ExtUtils/xsubpp lib/ExtUtils/xsubpp
ntoarmv7-gcc -DPERL_CORE --sysroot=/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fPIC -Wno-unused-function -c -o op.o op.c
./miniperl_top lib/unicore/mktables -w -C lib/unicore -P pod -maketest -makelist -p
./miniperl_top: no ./miniperl found; build it before using miniperl_top
make: *** [lib/unicore/CombiningClass.pl] Error 1
```

I couldn't find much info on how to resolve the above issues. Could it be because i have not provided correct setting options for ./configure ?? If so, can you provide more insight on this.

EDIT:

It looks like i was passing the wrong information to ./configure script (it was considering it as the native rather than cross), I updated it with the following and was able to make bit of progress.

```
./configure -Dsysroot=/opt/qnx6 -Dcc=arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.6.0eabi-gcc --target-tools-prefix=arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.6.0eabi- --target=arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.6.0eabi  --host=arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.6.0eabi -Dprefix=$HOME/localperl
```

with this, the configuration was successfull for the cross platform. Now when I perform the make, it runs fine for a bit and I run it following error

```
arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.6.0eabi-ar cru libperl.a op.o perl.o gv.o toke.o perly.o pad.o regcomp.o dump.o dquote.o util.o mg.o reentr.o mro_core.o hv.o av.o run.o pp_hot.o sv.o pp.o scope.o pp_ctl.o pp_sys.o doop.o doio.o regexec.o utf8.o taint.o deb.o universal.o globals.o perlio.o perlapi.o numeric.o mathoms.o locale.o pp_pack.o pp_sort.o keywords.o caretx.o time64.o DynaLoader.o
arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.6.0eabi-ranlib libperl.a
./miniperl_top statars  > static.list
./miniperl_top extlibs  > ext.libs
 arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.6.0eabi-gcc -DPERL_CORE --sysroot=/opt/qnx6 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -c -o perlmain.o perlmain.c

arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.6.0eabi-gcc --sysroot=/opt/qnx6 -Wl,-E -o perl perlmain.o libperl.a   
libperl.a(pp.o): In function `Perl_pp_crypt':
pp.c:(.text+0xffd8): warning: The 'crypt' function has been deprecated in libc. Link against liblogin for extended algorithm support.
libperl.a(toke.o): In function `Perl_scan_num':
toke.c:(.text+0x27b82): undefined reference to `pow'
libperl.a(util.o): In function `Perl_drand48_r':
util.c:(.text+0xa36e): undefined reference to `ldexp'
libperl.a(sv.o): In function `S_hextract':
sv.c:(.text+0x13ca0): undefined reference to `frexp'
libperl.a(sv.o): In function `Perl_sv_vcatpvfn_flags':
sv.c:(.text+0x16cc0): undefined reference to `frexp'
libperl.a(time64.o): In function `Perl_gmtime64_r':
time64.c:(.text+0x338c): undefined reference to `fmod'
.
.
time64.c:(.text+0x359c): undefined reference to `floor'
time64.c:(.text+0x37e6): undefined reference to `ceil'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [perl] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

final problem was related to linking the libraries. adding -lm fixed the problem

```
arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.6.0eabi-gcc --sysroot=/opt/qnx660/target/qnx6 -Wl,-rpath,/home/swgroup/localperl/lib/perl5/5.24.0/arm-/CORE -Wl,-E -o perl perlmain.o libperl.so -lm
```